# Materialized View Refresh through db-link: method "?" is fast, method "c" takes forever?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c, materialized-views

In Oracle 19c, I have an MV which simply duplicates data from a remote table through a DB-link.

When doing a refresh of the MV with the method='c', the update takes forever (half an hour), but doing the update using method='?' (which is `FORCE` according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dwhsg/refreshing-materialized-views.html)) in seconds.

As far as I understood, due to lack if indices for the incremental update, MV refreshes via linked DB's only works in a complete way. So therefore, `FORCE` should fall back to 'c'.

I am obviously wrong somewhere or missing something. Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Per the docs, `?` allows complete, fast, or PCT (partition change tracking), selecting the best given what's possible. If you don't have a materialized view log created on the source, it can't be fast, but it might be PCT if the source table is partitioned. If so, then it only needs replace the data corresponding to source partitions that have been modified and can skip those that haven't. If there haven't been any modifications it may even be instant because there's nothing to do.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Materialized View Logs have any effect over DB-Links, but your explanation totally makes sense. Most of the time, updates are done immediately, indicating there were no changes to be propagated.